# WordPress Hide post in front page based on user role

Tags: wordpress

I have custom user role "advertiser" and want to exclude their posts "which post by the user of advertiser roles" from front page.

Comment: Did you try anything ? Some usefull resources https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/

Comment: u tried this this is just to exclude base on post id. i wan to exclude base on user role

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to have a category "Advertisement" for example and to use `pre_get_posts` to exclude this category from your query. Each time an advertiser publish a new post, he will need to add this category.

For example

```php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'front_page_pre_get_posts');
function front_page_pre_get_posts($query) {

  if(is_front_page() && $query->is_main_query()) {
     $query->set('category__not_in', array(1)); // Replace 1 by the category ID

  }

}
```

I'm aware that this is not an answer yo your specific question. It's more like an advice. I'm gonna test some code to do exactly what you want and i'll update my answer with it.

### UPDATE

Not tested, but something like this should work.

- Add a hook on `pre_get_posts`
- First you get the users with the role that you want
- then you exclude those authors in the query

```php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'front_page_pre_get_posts');
function front_page_pre_get_posts($query) {
  // Get the users related to your role
  $args = array(
    // The role you want to exclude in your get post
    'role'   => 'advertiser',
    // Will return an array of ids
    'fields' => 'ids'
  );
  $users = get_users($args);


  if(is_front_page() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    // To exclude authors you can add a "-" before the id id of the author
    $query->set('author', '-'.implode(',-', $users)); // Will generate a string like "-1,-45,-48"

  }
}
```

Comment: well is not a website i developed so i just carry with what it is , and yeah this not the answer i tried this

Comment: And again ... sorry i forgot  $users in implode()

Comment: will test this but for now i just used the author id to exclude